# Android webview not loading local string

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to load the following content into my webview: I get it by making http request. It returns me the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        if (!document.cookie || document.cookie.indexOf('AVPDCAP=') == -1)
        { document.write('
 <scr'+'ipt src="http://....the redirect link...." type="text/javascript"></scr'+'ipt>'); }


</script>
```

I do the following to load it:

```
bannerContentWV = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.bannerFull);
bannerContentWV.setWebViewClient(new mWebViewClient());
bannerContentWV.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
bannerContentWV.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
bannerContentWV.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
bannerContentWV.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
bannerContentWV.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
bannerContentWV.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
bannerContentWV.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
bannerContentWV.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

But it shows a blank page. Can that be because the string i am trying to load into webview contains only script?

**EDIT:** When I inspect the html source, i see there are other html tags and codes but http get only returns me this script. Why?

Thanks

Comment: Better you put the <Script> in a separate /asset/html page and load it from assets rather loading directly

Comment: @BhavikMehta that works, you may want to write it as an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its more easy and reliable if you put such  in a separate HTML page, Put that HTML page in /asset
and load it to WebView from /asset as

```
WebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/yourhtmlfile.html");
```

Answer (score 1):

i had similar issue. I just put my script in HTML tag and put that page in live domain. Thats it. :) Hope this works...

Comment: I do not know whether that works for me but i solved the issue by saving the script in a file and loading the webview with that file. Thanks anyway